# Palo Alto API: how to iterate to get logs page by page?

Tags: ruby, logging

I have a ruby program that retrieves logs from Panorama using the API.

You start with:

```
  response = pa.api_request( :post, 'api/',
                {'type' => 'log', "log-type" => "threat" ,
                 "query" => "..."
                })
```

this returns a `jobid` which you then use in a subsequent call to retrieve logs:

```
pa.api_request( :post, 'api/', {type: 'log', action: 'get', 'job-id': pa.job_id })
```

which returns:

```
{"response"=>
  {"status"=>"success",
   "result"=>
    {"job"=>
      {"tenq"=>"13:03:30",
       "tdeq"=>"13:03:30",
       "tlast"=>"12:00:00",
       "status"=>"FIN",
       "id"=>"9315",
       "cached_logs"=>"220"},
     "log"=>
      {"logs"=>
        {"count"=>"20",
         "progress"=>"100",
...
```

One can retrieve only up to 5000 logs at a time. I presume that one can iterate this some how to get large numbers of log records using the information in the job section but I cannot figure out how.